# Info window overlapped by custom div element as map is not auto panning

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have a custom div which is positioned absolute on google map. Please see the image below.My problem is info window is overlapped by the custom div element as shown in the picture below.

[image: info window overlapping]

I want that map should pan when i click on the marker and then info window should open.

I am trying to achieve similar result like [Google my map](https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/). see the picture from google my map below. In google my map when I click on the marker the info window near to the top layer div (The div showing 'Untitled map' text) is not overlapped. Map auto panes when info window opens.

[image: google my map]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var map;
var chicago = {
  lat: 41.85,
  lng: -87.65
};

/**
 * The CenterControl adds a control to the map that recenters the map on
 * Chicago.
 * This constructor takes the control DIV as an argument.
 * @constructor
 */
function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Center Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago);
  });

}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: chicago
  });

  // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the CenterControl()
  // constructor passing in this DIV.
  var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);

  centerControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

use internal autocomplete, otherwise it's going to be issue for you, all balloon are part of that canvas, so if something is positioned on map canvas.

To fix this you can make is transparent while not hovering over that div.

Comment: "internal autocomplete" can you please say something more about this? Its confusing, because i am not trying to implement 'place autocomplete' feature.

Comment: then what you're trying to do with that div?

Comment: I will show some kind of text or anything on that div. Its is just a normal div element.

Comment: then you can do this opacity hack to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, "Control Position" is a good option, but I am using a div at absolute position. And I'll face more complexity if i use control position, rather than a normal div.